# Validation rule, alert when a field is NOT empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, rule, required

I know how to check if a field is empty and generate an alert if so:

```
$('#checkout-form').validate({
    rules: {
        first_name: {
            minlength: 2,
            required: true
        },
        ...
    }
});
```

But what is the opposite of `required`? I want to check and generate an alert when my field isn't empty.

Comment: "alert when my field isn't empty" - Why in the name of all that is holy would you want to do that?

Comment: @Jonathan An alert is not necessarily a bad thing (in OP's case I think he's referring to it as a "notice"), perhaps "you filled out this field, which is OK - just remember that it's only for people living here - you know that, right?", though `validate()` would (afaic) just pop out with an error, and in that case I completely agree with you.

Comment: @h2ooooooo of course, however in such a case a ***balloon popup*** may be better, some ones may understand the `alert` as the window shown by `alert()` function, that's totally annoying.

Comment: @KingKing Completely agree - I'm sort of hoping that "alert" in OP's sense is not necessarily the `alert()` function but rather a notice or a confirmation box. "Generate an alert" is not necessarily the same as "Run the `alert()` command".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#checkout-form').validate({
  rules: {
    first_name: {
      minlength: 2,
      required: true,
      equalToParam: ""
    },
```

But 'Why in the name of all that is holy would you want to do that?'

Comment: Thanks! It's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to create a new validator method:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    'empty',
    function (value) {
        return value === '';
    },
    'Must be empty'
);
```

You can then use `empty` as a validation constraint for that field.

That said, I'm really struggling to see a scenario where this would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure how this works. Where do I put it in my code? It says that there's an unexpected identifier at the line function(value).... I'm a total noob in jquery/javascript :/